# Which is best to use between the IN and JOIN operators in SQL server for the list of values as table two?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I heard that the `IN` operator is costlier than the `JOIN` operator.
Is that true?

Example case for IN operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one 
WHERE column_one IN (SELECT column_one FROM table_two)
```

Example case for JOIN operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one TOne 
JOIN (select column_one from table_two) AS TTwo
    ON TOne.column_one = TTwo.column_one
```

In the above query, which is recommended to use and why?

Comment: Your first query isn't valid SQL syntax and will receive a compilation error and should include a WHERE and a colmn for the IN: SELECT * FROM table_one 
WHERE column_one IN (SELECT column_one FROM table_two).
Also consider EXISTS as an alternative to IN

Comment: The two queries are different.  The second can return duplicate results if the column is repeated in the second table.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr;** - once the queries are fixed so that they will yield the same results, the performance is the same.

Both queries are not the same, and **will yield different results.**

The `IN` query will return all the columns from `table_one`,
while the `JOIN` query will return all the columns from both tables.

That can be solved easily by replacing the `*` in the second query to `table_one.*`, or better yet, specify only the columns you want to get back from the query (which is best practice).

However, even if that issue is changed, the queries might still yield different results if the values on `table_two.column_one` are not unique.
The `IN` query will yield a single record from `table_one` even if it fits multiple records in `table_two`, while the `JOIN` query will simply duplicate the records as many times as the criteria in the `ON` clause is met.

Having said all that - if the values in `table_two.column_one` are guaranteed to be unique, and the `join` query is changed to `select table_one.*...` - then, and only then, will both queries yield the same results - and that would be a valid question to compare their performance.

So, in the performance front:

The `IN` operator has a history of poor performance with a large values list - in earlier versions of SQL Server, if you would have used the `IN` operator with, say, 10,000 or more values, it would have suffer from a performance issue.

With a small values list (say, up to 5,000, probably even more) there's absolutely no difference in performance.

However, in currently supported versions of SQL Server (that is, 2012 or higher), the query optimizer is smart enough to understand that in the conditions specified above these queries are equivalent and might generate exactly the same execution plan for both queries - so performance will be the same for both queries.

**UPDATE:** I've done some performance research, on the only available version I have for SQL Server which is 2016 . 
First, I've made sure that `Column_One` in `Table_Two` is unique by setting it as the primary key of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE Table_One
(
    id int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Table_One PRIMARY KEY(Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Table_Two
(
    column_one int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Table_Two PRIMARY KEY(column_one)
);
```

Then, I've populated both tables with 1,000,000 (one million) rows.

```
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As N INTO Tally
FROM sys.objects A
CROSS JOIN sys.objects B
CROSS JOIN sys.objects C;

INSERT INTO Table_One (id) 
SELECT N
FROM Tally;

INSERT INTO Table_Two (column_one) 
SELECT N 
FROM Tally;
```

Next, I've ran four different ways of getting all the values of table_one that matches values of table_two. - The first two are from the original question (with minor changes), the third is a simplified version of the `join` query, and the fourth is a query that uses the `exists` operator with a correlated subquery instead of the `in` operaor`,

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_one
WHERE Id IN (SELECT column_one FROM table_two);

SELECT TOne.* 
FROM table_one TOne 
JOIN (select column_one from table_two) AS TTwo
    ON TOne.id = TTwo.column_one;

SELECT TOne.* 
FROM table_one TOne 
JOIN table_two AS TTwo
    ON TOne.id = TTwo.column_one;  

SELECT * 
FROM table_one
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table_two
    WHERE column_one = id
);
```

All four queries yielded the exact same result with [the exact same execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hyhpocirr) - so from it's safe to say performance, under these circumstances, are exactly the same.

[You can copy the full script (with comments) from Rextester](https://rextester.com/FKUU23363) (result is the same with any number of rows in the tally table).

Comment: . . This is misleading.  The OP doesn't specify that that the columns are primary keys in the question.  Hence, the two queries s/he mentions don't necessary return the same results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ...Which is why I've started my answer with "Both queries are not the same, and **will yield different results.**" followed by a detailed explanation on why, addressing both the usage of `*` and the issue with non-unique matches in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

From the point of performance view, mostly, using `EXISTS` might be a better option rather than using `IN` operator and `JOIN` among the tables :

```
SELECT TOne.*
  FROM table_one TOne
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table_two TTwo WHERE TOne.column_one = TTwo.column_one )
```

If you need the columns from both tables, and provided those have indexes on the column `column_one` used in the join condition, using a `JOIN` would be better than using an `IN` operator, since you will be able to benefit from the indexes :

```
SELECT TOne.*, TTwo.*
  FROM table_one TOne
  JOIN table_two TTwo
    ON TOne.column_one = TTwo.column_one
```

Answer (score 0):

> In the above query, which is recommended to use and why?

The second (JOIN) query cannot be optimal compare to first query unless you put `where` clause within sub-query as follows:

```
Select * from table_one TOne 
JOIN (select column_one from table_two where column_tow = 'Some Value') AS TTwo
ON TOne.column_one = TTwo.column_one
```

However, the better decision can be based on execution plan with following points into consideration:

1. How many tasks the query has to perform to get the result
2. What is task type and execution time of each task
3. Variance between `Estimated number of row` and `Actual number of rows` in each task - this can be fixed by `UPDATED STATISTICS on TABLE` if the variance too high.

In general, the [Logical Processing Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of the `SELECT` statement goes as follows, considering that if you manage your query to read the less amount of rows/pages at higher level (as per following order) would make that query less logical I/O cost and eventually query is more optimized. i.e. It's optimal to get rows filtered within `From` or `Where` clause rather than filtering it in `GROUP BY`  or `HAVING` clause.

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP