# I need help to Convert a SQL Statement to C# LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

I need help with Converting this Select statement in `LINQ C#` Code

```
SELECT TagName 
from Tags 
Where TagId IN(
    SELECT TagId 
    from PresentationTags 
    Where PresentationId = 2
)
```

Comment: I wonder if your SQL is well thought. Performance wise, it looks like you should do a inner join instead of a subselect

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bradbury9 That's inaccurate. An `IN` query is not always equivalent to a `JOIN` query, and the query optimizer is usually smart enough to create the same execution plan when they are equivalent. For more details, read [this SO question and my answer to it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57766248/3094533)

Comment: I'd suggest looking at: http://www.sqltolinq.com/ for future queries

Comment: if your PresentationTags and Tags are related in your model, you could do `from t in Tags where t.PresentationTags.PresentationId == 2 select t.TagName`. Note I am not adding this as an answer, because I lack information of your model.

Comment: @ZoharPeled If the name of the tables resemble the actual tables, they are very probably related, so a join could be used.

Comment: @bradbury9 Of course a join could be used, but not every `JOIN` is equivalent to every `IN` - for example, if `TagId` isn't unique in `PresentationTags`, then an `IN` query will return less results than a `JOIN` query will return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Where()` with nested `Any()` should do the job

```
context.Tags.Where(
    x => context.PresentationTags.Any(
        y => y.PresentationId == 2 && x.TagId == y.TagId
    )
).Select(x => x.TagName);
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind the reformatting - it's just easier to read when you don't have to scroll.